# Why `go test` complains undefined _test

Tags: go

I am new to Go. Why `go test` complains about the undefined test, while `go test countdown_test.go main.go` is fine?

```
❯ go test
# main.test
/var/folders/1z/p_x3q6b53mdf7_536x8_8h2h0000gn/T/go-build2418758029/b001/_testmain.go:13:2: cannot import "main"
/var/folders/1z/p_x3q6b53mdf7_536x8_8h2h0000gn/T/go-build2418758029/b001/_testmain.go:21:20: undefined: _test
FAIL    main [build failed]
```

In the directory where I run the command has three files,

main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func Countdown(out *bytes.Buffer) {
    fmt.Fprint(out, "3")
}
```

countdown_test.go:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "testing"
)

func TestCountdown(t *testing.T) {
    buffer := &bytes.Buffer{}

    Countdown(buffer)

    got := buffer.String()
    want := "3"

    if got != want {
        t.Errorf("got %q want %q", got, want)
    }
}
```

go.mod:

```
module main

go 1.17
```

Comment: Cant reproduce.

Comment: Do not name your module "main" or "test" or "stdlib". Use "my.main.module".

Answer (score 0):

Passed after changing the module name in go.mod file to:

```
module Countdown

go 1.17
```

Before change:

```
PS D:\##\##\##> go test
# main.test
C:\##\##\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build2311367811\b001\_testmain.go:13:2: cannot import "main"
C:\##\##\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build2311367811\b001\_testmain.go:21:20: undefined: _test
FAIL    main [build failed]
```

After changing the module name:

```
PS D:\##\##\##> go test
PASS
ok      Countdown       0.037s
```

Please check this [refrence](https://go.dev/doc/modules/gomod-ref).

I will quote the important thing form it:

```
Even if you’re not at first intending to make your module available for use from other code, using its repository path is a best practice that will help you avoid having to rename the module if you publish it later.
```